# What are the differences between MBean and Perf Mbean?

Tags: websphere, mbeans

I'm working on a small task that uses Mbean and PerfMbean to extract performance data from PMI layer.

but actually, I do not understand how Mbean and perfMbean distributed across WebSphere components, like:

How many **PerfMbean** per cell? per profile? per cluster? per node? WAS?

the same question for **Mbean**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some mbeans there is only one per cell, others  have one for each JVM, or for only certain JVM's in the cell. Only mbeans for processes and apps that are started are visible.

If you connect to the dmgr using wsadmin (using Jython) you can see all the active WebSphere mbeans in the cell with this command:

print AdminControl.queryNames('WebSphere:*')

Based on the output of that, there appears to be one Perf mbean for each node (running on the node agent) and one on each Appserver.

The available mbeans are documented here: 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/mbeanDocs/index.html